# Use Right click instead of left click for a unity button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button

I'm making a game in Unity and I created a dialog with a dynamic set of button replies that get generated in a button prefab via code. I coded the button to go to the next line of dialogue like this:

```
 btn.GetComponentInChildren<Button>().onClick.AddListener((() =>
                        {
                            AnswerClicked(index);
                        }));
```

But what if insead I want to use the right mouse button to run `AnswerClicked(index);`?
When I had static button options I would add a script called `RightButtonEvent`that checked the position of the cursor and if the user right-clicked like this:

```
 void Update()
    {
        if ((Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))&&(isOver))
        {
            onRightDown.Invoke();
        }
    }

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        isOver = true;
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        isOver = false;
    }
}
```

How can I implement this in the dynamic button I have above?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using button component for this, add script to UI component that you want to interact and use [OnPointerDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable.OnPointerDown.html). For checking if mouse click is left/right, use [PointerEventData.button](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.PointerEventData-button.html) that accesible from **OnPointerDown** method. Here is sample how to get button:

```
public virtual void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (eventData.button == PointerEventData.InputButton.Right)
        // Do what you want
}
```

Comment: This the basically the same thing as the `RightButtonEvent'. I can't put this in the prefab that parents the dynamic button options. I have a dynamic index of answers available, I have no fixed number of ui elements. The index depends on a scriptable object that contains the dialog text and answers.  Based on the number of index, it creates a number of child buttons as answers. thats why I use `btn.GetComponentInChildren<Button>` how can I produce the same result but with right click?

Comment: First remove button component from your prefab. Then, you can create a MonoBehaviour script that implements [OnPointerDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable.OnPointerDown.html). You can easily check for **RMB** there. Finally, attach script as component to your prefab when instantiating it.